How can I cancel a property change using OnIsSwitchChanging with ObservableProperty in .NET MAUI?
I'm trying to cancel property changes under certain conditions using OnIsSwitchChanging with ObservableProperty in .NET MAUI. However, I'm not entirely sure how to achieve this. I appreciate any help or guidance on this matter!
    [ObservableProperty]
private bool isSwitch;
partial void OnIsSwitchChanging(bool oldValue, bool newValue)
{
    if (someConditions)
    {
        //Cancel change operation 
    }
}


Have you tried adding the condition in the setter method?

When using :
[ObservableProperty]
private bool isSwitch;

This will auto generate code behind the scene, for auto update and notify when the status changed.
The important part of that is :
When using a lower case of the first letter of the variable name: [isSwitch],
you must use the uppercase of it [IsSwitch] for binding or other operations.
In addition to that auto generated code, there will be actions can be used


partial void On[......]Changing (bool oldValue, bool newValue) {}



partial void On[......]Changing (bool Value) {}



partial void On[......]Changed (bool oldValue, bool newValue) {}



partial void On[......]Changed (bool Value) {}



Note: [......] = IsSwitch
In your case, we should use action No.1 when the value is going to change and having an old and new value:
partial void OnIsSwitchChanging(bool oldValue, bool Value)
{   
    // To prevent loop
    if (oldValue == newValue)
        return;

    if (someConditions)
    {
        //Cancel change operation
        IsSwitch = oldValue;
    }
}


If you read this Running code upon changes, you will find that the general code is complex and you cannot change the value unless you change the logic in Setters.
So the easiest workaround is to set the condition in Setters.
    private bool isSwitch;

    public bool IsSwitch
    {
        get => isSwitch;
        set
        {
            if (some condition)
            {
                SetProperty(ref isSwitch, value);
            }
        }
    }

Hope it helps!
